# I want to learn how to implement a* path finding in Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I found this code online and would really like for someone to explain it simply. I understand most of the initialisation of nodes, but don't understand as much once I get further down. If someone can explain the code near line by line, I would be grateful. The areas I find the most confusing are the calculation sections.

Thanks for any/all responses

```
class Node():

    def __init__(self, parent=None, position=None):
        self.parent = parent
        self.position = position

        self.g = 0
        self.h = 0
        self.f = 0

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.position == other.position


    def astar(maze, start, end):
        """Returns a list of tuples as a path from the given start to the given end in the given maze"""

        # Create start and end node
        start_node = Node(None, start)
        start_node.g = start_node.h = start_node.f = 0
        end_node = Node(None, end)
        end_node.g = end_node.h = end_node.f = 0

        # Initialize both open and closed list
        open_list = []
        closed_list = []

        # Add the start node
        open_list.append(start_node)

        # Loop until you find the end
        while len(open_list) > 0:

            # Get the current node
            current_node = open_list[0]
            current_index = 0
            for index, item in enumerate(open_list):
                if item.f < current_node.f:
                    current_node = item
                    current_index = index

            # Pop current off open list, add to closed list
            open_list.pop(current_index)
            closed_list.append(current_node)

            # Found the goal
            if current_node == end_node:
                path = []
                current = current_node
                while current is not None:
                    path.append(current.position)
                    current = current.parent
                return path[::-1] # Return reversed path

            # Generate children
            children = []
            for new_position in [(0, -1), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (1, 0), (-1, -1), (-1, 1), (1, -1), (1, 1)]: # Adjacent squares

            # Get node position
            node_position = (current_node.position[0] + new_position[0], current_node.position[1] + new_position[1])

            # Make sure within range
            if node_position[0] > (len(maze) - 1) or node_position[0] < 0 or node_position[1] > (len(maze[len(maze)-1]) -1) or node_position[1] < 0:
                continue

            # Make sure walkable terrain
            if maze[node_position[0]][node_position[1]] != 0:
                continue

            # Create new node
            new_node = Node(current_node, node_position)

            # Append
            children.append(new_node)

        # Loop through children
        for child in children:

            # Child is on the closed list
            for closed_child in closed_list:
                if child == closed_child:
                    continue

            # Create the f, g, and h values
            child.g = current_node.g + 1
            child.h = ((child.position[0] - end_node.position[0]) ** 2) + ((child.position[1] - end_node.position[1]) ** 2)
            child.f = child.g + child.h

            # Child is already in the open list
            for open_node in open_list:
                if child == open_node and child.g > open_node.g:
                    continue

            # Add the child to the open list
            open_list.append(child)


def main():

    maze = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

    start = (0, 0)
    end = (7, 6)

    path = astar(maze, start, end)
    print(path)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a tutoring service. Please see: [help/on-topic], [ask], [tour].

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you first understand the A* algorithm itself, here is a good video i found, check [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-L-WgKMFuhE). After understanding this, try to code it yourself in whatever language you want and then if you can't understand something ask about that stuff on SO.